# ext4 data recovery

Tags: data-recovery, ext4, data-loss

So yesterday I followed this guide : https://www.supergrubdisk.org/wiki/SGD_Howto_make

was making a key for a friend and I typed (don't type this)

```
sudo dd if=super_grub2_disk_hybrid_2.02s9.iso of=/dev/sdc
```

instead of

```
sudo dd if=super_grub2_disk_hybrid_2.02s9.iso of=/dev/sde
```

sde woulda been my usb key sdc was my 4TBs of storage.

it's a ext4 partition

is my data forever gone or is there a way to get it back?

knowing that formatting the drive would have taken 4-5 minutes at best the dd command took 15 milliseconds.

update so I've successfully run tesdisk and gdisk on my disk but I'm seemingly not out of the woods yet, now I get a different message when trying to mount it :

[image]

but it goes back to the old after a reboot :

[image]

SECOND UPDATE :

new idea : what if I just format the hard drive to ex GPT (the original filetype, which clearly it doesn't have right now. right now it's just formatless and headless)  (since clearly this doesn't delete the data : testdisk can see and browse it) and then run testdisk to place the data back?

I think I will run into issues trying to format though, because of dd.

how do make a hard drive formatable again after dd?

Comment: most of your data is there if not all, search how to use backup superblock ext4

Comment: You overwrote the first part of drive or the size of supergrub ISO. But if 4TB it should have backup partition table at end of drive. Was it only one extremely large partition or multiple partitions? What does this show? `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdc` I really do not like the dd method of creating bootable flash drives, dd is known as Data Destroyer for a reason and many of us have typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fairly recent backup, I think it is easier and faster to use it instead of trying to repair the file system or recover the files from the damaged file system. But there are ways even if there is no recent backup.

The following link may help,

[Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)

Scroll down to 'Advanced repair of a partition table, file system and/or recovery of files'

- **If there are important data, that you must recover, it is a good idea to do the repair work on a cloned copy.**
- You can try according to @oldfred's comment about **recovering the partition table from the backup table** at the tail end of the drive. He might give you more details about it, if you ask.

  Edit: I found some details in the manual for `gdisk`,

  ```
  man gdisk
  ```

  > **The second gdisk menu is the recovery & transformation menu**, which provides  access  to  data  recovery  options  and features related to the transformation of partitions between partitioning  schemes  (converting
  >   BSD  disklabels  into  GPT  partitions  or  creating  hybrid  MBRs, for
  >   instance).  A few options on this menu duplicate functionality  on  the
  >   main menu, for the sake of convenience. The options on this menu are:
  >
  > **b**      Rebuild  GPT  header  from  backup.  You  can use the backup GPT header to rebuild the main GPT header  with  this  option.  It's
  >   likely  to  be  useful  if  your  main GPT header was damaged or
  >   destroyed (say, by sloppy use of dd).
- If that is successful, you can try to **repair the `ext4` file system**, which is also described in the link above.
- You can **try several different tools**, one of them is Testdisk, that you have tried already.
- **If nothing else works, there is [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/)**, that can recover files from the data stored on the drive surface without any working file system. It is a lot of work, and generally the file names are lost and the directory structure is lost. In some files, the file name is stored among the file data, and in those cases the file name can be restored.

Comment: Hey! thanks for the reply I've gotten further ahead. I think testdisk actually restored my data but that I now need to add the filesystem back in. it used to be GPT.

Comment: I rangdisk sussefully I've updated my op.

Comment: @tatsu, It is possible, that too much is damaged. But if you are lucky, you may be able to repair your ext4 file system. Otherwise you can resort to PhotoRec, which can recognize the data on the drive and identify the file headers of several common file types. In other words, PhotoRec can recover files even if the file system is damaged beyond repair.

Comment: updated the OP again

Comment: @tatsu, **don't format before you have finished the recovery work**. Do as little as possible with the drive. All actions might damage/overwrite the data that are still possible to recover. -- After you have finished the recovery work, it is OK to format it (to create a new partition table, partitions and file systems).

Comment: Ok but how about I try that on a cloned copy of the drive?

Comment: Yes, that is a good idea :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68065/discussion-between-sudodus-and-tatsu).

Answer (score 1):

You probably can get some data back using testdisk

```
sudo apt install testdisk
```

I would create an image of the drive with dd `sudo dd if=/dev/sde of=/path/to/backup.img` and run testdisk against that image but with a 4TB drive that can take some time.

Comment: I'm using testdisk. it findsthe old partition and does the steps but on rebbot it still doesn't show up. so how eacetly step by step (in testdisk) would I do what you say? thanks btw