# Missing mount button in hard drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I was unintentionally formatted my hard drive then i cancel it after few seconds. But after that my hard drive cant be mounted, its button disappeared. I have tried

> `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/DATA`

and it goes

> `mount: /media/DATA: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

here for my disk status[missing mount button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uSEk.png)

Comment: You formatted your harddrive, but cancelled: so now, whatever partition info is there is corrupt. You will need to reformat, If there is data you need to recover, you may first need to attempt data recovery using testdisk, which may recover deleted partitions, or photorec, that can recover data fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not that there is a missing mount button. Your problem is that currently, your partition is corrupt because of your unintentional attempt to format it.

You (unintentionally) started formatting. Thus, a new file system was being created. However, you interrupted the process. As a result, the new file system being created is not properly written: a partition is seen, but no valid file system is recognized by the system.

You now need to reformat the partition, and have the formatting correctly go to completion, to put a valid file system on that partition.

If there is data on that drive for which you do not have a backup, there will be a problem. You can [attempt data recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971705/ext4-data-recovery), but it is not trivial.